# assigned input values to array based on whether they have changed jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, attributes, onchange

I couldn't find anything, but I feel like it's been asked before.

I have multiple inputs:

```
<input id="id1" class="abc" name="tags" "value="test1" />
<input id="id2" class="abc" name="tags" "value="test2" />
```

When the user changes the value of the input, I want the script to pick it up and assign it into an array.

What I have:

```
jQuery('.abc').change(function() {
        var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        var name = jQuery(this).attr('name');
        var value = jQuery(this).val();
        var ch = {};
        ch[id][name] = value;
        alert(ch[id][name]);
    });
```

But from the start, it didn't work. `jQuery(this).attr('id')` doesn't exist as a function.  I think the reason this isn't working is because there isn't a specific class I am calling, but I don't know.  Maybe I've been staring at code too much, but it's not working!

the error: `can't convert undefined to object`

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you receive? Also, where is `ch` defined?

Comment: where and how is `ch` defined?

Comment: edited:  left out the array declaration, my bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new object for `ch[id]`

```
jQuery('.abc').change(function () {
  var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
  var name = jQuery(this).attr('name');
  var value = jQuery(this).val();
  var ch = {};
  ch[id] = {}; // <-- here
  ch[id][name] = value;
  alert(ch[id][name]);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tq2CJ/

Answer (score 0):

In your case 'this' points to function() not to your instance of jQuery('.abc') as you might expect.  See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html for an explanation on this.